# Play video file randomly from a folder recursively looking down into all directory structure tree

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, html5-video

Some JavaScript, JQuery or PHP that will look into a folder recursively down into all directory structure tree, finds and loads a new video file into the html5 video tag source so it plays automatically each time when page is reloaded. A plus, when finish playing, jumps to another video file ramdomly & seamlessly.

This will work for one selected folder, but does not work down into all directory structure tree

```
<?php
$myVideoDir = '.';
$extension = 'mp4';
$videoFile = false;
$pseudoDir = scandir($myVideoDir);
$myitems = array();
$mycounter = 0;
foreach($pseudoDir as $item) {
    if ( $item != '..' && $item != '.' && !is_dir($item) ) {
        $ext = preg_replace('#^.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$#', '$1', $item);
        if ( $ext == $extension )
            $videoFile = $item;
            if ( $videoFile <> "" ) {
                $myitems[] = $videoFile;
                $mycounter = $mycounter + 1;
            }               
    }
}

$myrandom = rand(0,$mycounter-1);
if ( !!$videoFile ) {

    echo '<video id="dep" class="center" width="400" autoplay controls>        
            <source src="'.$myVideoDir.'/'.$myitems[$myrandom].'" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$mycounter` updated? As far as I can see, it is `0` at all times.

Comment: inside the if ( $videoFile <> "" ) statement  ...

Comment: How often do you expect it to get updated?

Comment: People add videos all the time, so I need to check everytime page gets loaded, play even new videos added just before page refreshed

Comment: Use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to drill into the tree. Depending on how many files you have your setup may become very slow and the $myItems array may cause memory limit problems. Better to store a record of the uploaded file in database and use the random functions if the database to give you a random record

Comment: Videos are downloaded and place into our server and each page can only go about 50 video files at most. Imagine a music band and its best hits. Then another band then its best 50 hits, so there will be no more than 50 video files per page. We dont have a database system to get records. Memory will not cause limit problems, our directory tree is not that deep. So what we want to do is just pick one song and then jump to another band song and so on.. 3 leves directory structure at most. Thanks in advanced

Comment: Got it to work, thanks a lot, here is the final code, minor adjustments done, maybe you can clean it up a little bit http://juntos.webtv.video/test2.php  thanks @Twisty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following code.

```
<?php
$myVideoDir = '.';
$extension = 'mp4';
$videoFile = false;
$pseudoDir = scandir($myVideoDir);
$myitems = array();
foreach($pseudoDir as $item) {
  if ( $item != '..' && $item != '.' && !is_dir($item) ) {
    $ext = preg_replace('#^.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$#', '$1', $item);
    if ( $ext == $extension ) {
      $videoFile = $item;
      if ( $videoFile <> "" ) {
        array_push($myitems, $videoFile);
      }               
    }
  }
}
$myrandom = rand(0,count($myitems)-1);
if ( !!$videoFile ) {
  echo '<video id="dep" class="center" width="400" autoplay controls><source src="'.$myVideoDir.'/'.$myitems[$myrandom].'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
}
?>
```

**Update**

Consider making a function.

```
<?php

function getFileList($dirPath, $ext){
  $list = scandir($dirPath);
  $fileList = array();
  foreach($list as $item) {
    if ($item != '..' && $item != '.' && !is_dir($item)) {
      $info = pathinfo($item);
      $videoFile = $item;
      if ($info['extension'] == $ext) {
        array_push($fileList, $item);
      }               
    }
  }
  return $fileList;
}

function pickRandVid($l){
  $r = rand(0, count($l) - 1);
  return $l[$r];
}

$myVideoDir = ".";
$dirList = scandir($myVideoDir);
$videoList = array()
foreach($dirList as $d){
  if(is_dir($d)){
    array_merge($videoList, getFileList($d, "mp4"));
  }
}

echo "<video id='dep' class='center' width='400' autoplay controls>\r\n";
echo "\t<source src='$myVideoDir/" . pickRandVid($videoList) . "' type='video/mp4' />\r\n";
echo "</video>\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: Great it simplifies a lot cleaner... there is an extra } but it works... I just now need to go into its folders and grab the video files inside that folder. Thanks @Twisty

Comment: I can play the videos here http://juntos.webtv.video/test.php on main folder, but I cant get the videos from the folders http://juntos.webtv.video/band1/ nor http://www.juntos.webtv.video/band2/

Comment: There are the correct number of brackets. Are these two folders the only two you need to sna for MP4 files?

Comment: I just edit your answer, there was one extra bracket. Dont worry. ... I was able to edit you answer. NO, there could be many folders, as musical bands on our server lets say 200 bands and 50 mp4s on each ... I just need front page to pick ramdon one song and play

Comment: Im glad you did understand my question, dont know why people down voted me on this valid question. I looked all over before I asked the right question. I appreciated your time and effort @Twisty

Comment: @LuisHCabrejo I saw your edit and rejected it. I have added an update that might be worth considering.

Comment: Debugging, getting 500 error, but it will work, I like it.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks a lot, here is the final code, minor adjustments done, maybe you can clean it up a little bit http://juntos.webtv.video/test2.php